# How can I stop intellisense from auto completing 'from' when typing linq query

Tags: c#, linq, intellisense

When I start typing a linq query, the "from" keyword is not suggested by default resulting in it auto completing on some other variable which is massively frustrating.

What I'm trying to type: `var myResult = (from x in myList)`

What I've actually typed: `var myResult = (from"SPACEBAR"`

What I end up with:
`var myResult = (someOtherVariableThatHasFromInIt)`

PS. If you tell me to do the linq query a different way you're missing the point.

Comment: Hit escape to drop the suggested list then hit the spacebar, kind of frustrating sometimes

Comment: You want to turn this off for one specific word?

Comment: @JSteward Esc works, but it's not 'developer friendly'.

Comment: Strange, I can't replicate this. Try flipping this setting anyway: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/01/22/intellisense-suggestion-mode/

Comment: @RufusL yes, I feel like this should be off for all of intellisense by default.

Comment: It is annoying sometimes, that said I only get this behavior if I'm typing and then have to backspace and restart typing the line. Not sure why it does this sometimes.

Comment: Ctrl+Z will undo the autocomplete and leave the space there

Comment: This repro's in VS2019, but specifically only occurs when attempting to enclose the `from` in `()`. As the autocomplete list I see has types at the top of it, and variables with *from* in their name at the bottom, my *suspicion* is that the intellisense assumption is that you're writing a *cast*. Yes it's wrong in this instance, but that's what ESC is for, so short of turning off intellisense entirely you may be out of luck

Answer (score 1):

If this is VS there is a button that switches from auto-completion to suggestions (shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+Space), the difference beeing that in suggestion mode you have to use tab (space bar doesn't insert automatically). The only problem is that when you close VS it returns to standard mode.

[image: Toggle mode]

If it's VS Code, add the following to "settings.json"

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
```